# Django order_by on custom model method

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
     transaction_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65, decimal_places=0, default=0)
     decimals = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Decimals", null=True, blank=True)

     def amount_convert(self):
        try:
            converted = transaction_amount / pow(10, decimals)
        except Exception:
            return None
```

Because transaction may contain different currency, each currency has different decimal value

I tried to use the query `Transactions.objects.filter(...).order_by('-transaction_amount')` but realized I have special case with different currencies

For example:

IN DB:

```
id=1, transaction_amount = 200000, decimals = 4 => amount_convert() = 20 
id=2, transaction_amount = 10000000, decimals = 6 => amount_convert() = 10
```

Should `id=1` be on top of `id=2` but the `transaction_amount` I'm querying is wrong.

So the `amount_convert()` model method is what I'm looking for when using `order_by()` method, but it seems like `order_by` doesn't support custom model method.
Is there a way I can use custom model method for sorting in the query?

Comment: are you tried objectmanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) what should be the output of `amount_convert` and `order_by` it. Like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, FloatField

transactions = Transactions.objects.annotate(
        converted_amount=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('transaction_amount')/pow(10, F('decimals')),
            output_field=FloatField()
        )
    ).order_by('-converted_amount')
```

Comment: can annotate accept string of `converted_amount=F('transaction_amount')/pow(10, F('decimals'))` ? because i need annotate to be dynamic. But great answer, i will accept when it allow me to

Comment: Sorry, I am not on clear what you intend to do here. Probably you can look at ExpressionWrapper: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.ExpressionWrapper

Comment: yes it need `ExpressionWrapper` and `output_field`  or else it will return `Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field` error

Comment: `Transactions.objects.annotate(
        converted_amount=ExpressionWrapper(F('transaction_amount')/pow(10, F('decimals'), output_field=FloatField())).order_by('-converted_amount')` 
Here is the correct query